# gulp task copying entire folder

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I have the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('sassComponents', function() {
  return gulp.src('sassComponents/**/mainScss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        'sourcemap=none': true,
         errLogToConsole: true
    })).on('error', notify.onError({
        title: "mistake: ",
        message: "<%= error.message %>"
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets/'));
});
```

I want it to take the `.scss` file in `sassComponents/**/mainScss/` and put it in `public/stylesheets` (and convert it to `.css`) but its copying the entire folder structure (not just the file):

`**/mainScss/sass.scss`

the conversion from `.scss` to `.css` is happening correctly, but how do I just get the sass file out, without the rest of the folders that it's in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
gulp.task('sassComponents', function(){
    return gulp.src('sassComponents/**/mainScss/*.scss', {base: "./"})
    .pipe(sass({
        'sourcemap=none': true,
        errLogToConsole: true
    })).on('error', notify.onError({
        title: "mistake: ",
        message: "<%= error.message %>"
    }))
    .pipe(rename({dirname:''}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets/'));
});
```

**EDIT**

To use the above code you'll need to install gulp-rename using npm:

```
npm install --save gulp-rename
```

And you'll need to declare it as a variable in your gulpfile

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
```

Comment: The .pipe(rename({dirname:''})) bit gets rid of the file structure

Comment: i'm getting an error `ReferenceError: rename is not defined` what node module is that (gulp-rename?)?

Comment: you will need gulp-rename, and rename = require('gulp-rename'),